# How do CSS specificity levels between classes/pseudo-classes and elements/pseudo-elements work?

Tags: css

I'm using the following definitions (adapted from the CSS2 spec http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity )

- a = using the style attribute on an
  element
- b = number of id attributes
- c = number of attributes (classes) and pseudo classes (:link, :hover)
- d = number of elements and pseudo-elements (:first-line, :first-letter)

With the following styles (my calculations to the right):

```
.content          {color: green;}   /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=0 -> 0,0,1,0 */
.content:hover    {color: yellow;}  /* a=0 b=0 c=2 d=0 -> 0,0,2,0 */
li                {color: orange;}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=1 -> 0,0,0,1 */
li:first-line     {color: pink;}    /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=2 -> 0,0,0,2 */
```

and the following html

```
<li class="content">The first line</li>
```

When I open it up in a browser, the line of text is pink.  I thought it would be green and on hover, it would be yellow. I thought that elements and pseudo-elements (the d in the calculation) have less weight than classes and pseudo classes (the c in the calculations).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The specificity of first-line and first-child in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555878/the-specificity-of-first-line-and-first-child-in-css)

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of specificity is completely correct. Pseudo-classes and classes are equal to each other in specificity, and both of them rank higher than pseudo-elements and elements (which are also equal to each other). This is [explained pretty clearly](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) at the spec you already linked to.

So why do the rules you set in `li:first-line` take precedence over the ones you set in `.content:hover`, if the latter is more specific?

Because, from CSS's perspective, pseudo-elements *are elements*. That means that you have a `li:first-line` element which - if you didn't style it - would *inherit* `color: green` or `color: yellow` from the `.content` and `.content:hover` rules. But rules that target an element directly always take precedence over inherited rules, and your `:first-line` selector is targeting a pseudo-element *within* your `li`. The `:first-line` rules win simply because they are not inherited and the rules from `.content` and `.content:hover` selectors *are* inherited (by the pseudo-element contained within the `li`). Specificity rules are a red herring; they don't even come into play.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `:first-line` is more specific than just `.content`. So the first line of the text *is* pink, but the bullet of the list *is* green (and yellow on hover). Everything is good, as for me.

Imagine that the `:first-line` selector is just a nested text node selector, like:

```
<li class="content">
     <text:text>The first line</text:text><br />
     The second line
</li>
```

It operates on the nested element, so it is more important than any other selector.

Comment: -1; this is incorrect. The OP's analysis of the spec is correct; `:first-line` is *not* more specific than `.content`. The reason `:first-line` takes precedence is that directly-applied styles take precedence over inherited styles; specificity is irrelevant.

Comment: Just reread this while in less of a rush and realised that everything *after* your first paragraph hits the nail on the head; it's just that your first paragraph gets it completely wrong. Without the first paragraph, this would be a good answer.