# The specificity of first-line and first-child in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
:first-line {
    color: red;
}
:first-child {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>asdasdasdsad<br>sdfsdfs</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is:

asdasdasdasd  <- red

sdfsdfs <- blue.

However, what I am thinking is that the p tag is the first child of body. first-child is a pseudo-class, which has a specificity of 10 and first-line is a pseudo-element, which has a specificity of 1. Therefore, both lines should be displayed as blue text, but I am apparently wrong.

Please point out my mistake. Thank you very much.

Comment: Mistake? It's not a mistake. It's the way CSS works. `:first-line` will overwrite styles applied to a *general* selector like `:first-child` is. First-line is applied to *content* as pseudo while the "parent" `:first-child` styles can be modified by specificity-precedence.

Answer (score 4):

The `:first-line` selector applies directly to the first line, while the `:first-child` selector is inherited from the element that it applies to.

A style that applies directly to the item takes precedence over inherited styles.

You can make the selector for the element more specific, by for example adding elements, id and class selectors, but it still can't take precedence over the style applied to the first line. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/3H4Ab/

Comment: thanks but I am still having trouble understanding why :first-line selector takes precedence. What's the mechanism behind this specificity calculation?

Comment: Specificity doesn’t really matter here; both rules actually apply—but to different elements. `:first-child` will apply the style to the `p` element, making its text color blue. As such, the first line will inherit that color from its parent (the `p` element). The `::first-line` rule however targets that first line directly, overwriting the style to a red text color, making it ignore the inherited value. It’s like how `<p>Foo <strong>bar</strong> baz</p>` will still make *“bar”* bold although a rule for `p` could make the font weight explicitely normal.

Comment: @ZesenHuang: There isn't any specificity calculation for that. The `:first-line` selector applies directly to the first line, while the `:first-child` selector applies to the `p` element. That makes the blue color an inherited style that doesn't take over the red color that is a style applied directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use `<br>`, sdfsdfs goes to a new line so it won't be the first line, but it will still be the first child of body tag and it will be blue. Also as you specified the color of the first line it will be red, as obvious. (Just trying to reason)

Answer (score 0):

> p tag is the first child of body. first-child is a pseudo-class, which has a specificity of 10 and first-line is a pseudo-element, which has a specificity of 1.

Well, no. `first-line` is inheriting the style and adds 1 pseudo-element inside the pseudo-class(10 1), so it's absolutely normal.

Answer (score 0):

I just read that

> In CSS 3, you need to differentiate pseudo-elements from
>   pseudo-classes by using a double colon (::) at the beginning of the
>   element.

on http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/